# Tess-Two, Tesseract Windows, different results

Tags: android, windows, ocr, tesseract, difference

I use tess-two for my android app. The recognition is bad but sometimes i works. I also use tesseract on my windows 7 pc and the same pictures get recognized 100% here. I tried different Options.

On windows i use:

```
    tesseract test.png output -eng -psm6
```

On android:

```
    Bitmap bMap = btm;
    final TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.init(dpath, lang);
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
    baseApi.setImage(bMap);
    outputText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

I also tried different PageSegMode's but do not get better recognitions.

Why is Windows tesseract working better? Do i make any mistakes?

I noticed that in Windows tesseract recognizes the numbers from top to bottom and in Tess-Two from left to right. Don't know if this helps any.

PS: here the picture I trie to recognize:
http://pbrd.co/1q4DClR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to recognize the same answers like on windows.
I made a new testcase in witch i didnt set any options.
I used

```
Bitmap bMap = btm;
final TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.init(dpath, lang);
baseApi.setImage(bMap);
outputText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

Thats all. And it worked. Needet two weeks to figure that out. I dont't know why there is a difference between

baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);

and no option, as this PageSegMode is the default mode. 
Hope i could help anybody.

Comment: No, the [default PSM mode](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r719/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html) is a different one.

Comment: Yes it is in tess-two: row 70 [link](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java)